# Selecting mail messages that meet one of four search criteria

Tags: sql, mysql, email

This is the current very repetitive and long SQL I have. Unfortunately I'm not that good at SQL to group this and get rid of the repetition.

```
select * from Mail 
where admin_status = 1 
and admin_id = 4 
and core_event_id =0 
and user_id !=0 
and mail_reply_status = 0 
and sent_to = 0
and admin_inbox_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)

or ( admin_status = 1 
and admin_id = 4  
AND sent_to = 0 
and mail_reply_status = 0 
and user_id != 0 
and core_event_inactive = 1)
and admin_inbox_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)

or (`subject` like 'RE:%' 
AND admin_status = 1 
AND `admin_id` = 4 
and core_event_id =0 
and user_id != 0 
and mail_reply_status = 0 
and sent_to = 4 )
and admin_inbox_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)

or (`subject` like 'RE:%' 
and admin_status = 1 
and admin_id = 4  
AND sent_to = 0 
and mail_reply_status = 0 
and user_id != 0 
and core_event_inactive = 1)
and admin_inbox_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the indentation is next to inexisting. The code is badly formatted. Are you scared of tabs? There's no excuse for a wall of unformatted SQL. [There are online tools to fix it for you!](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20prettify)

---

You should have **all** keywords in capitals. Why is that? Well, it's an old convention that comes from times where there was no syntax highlighting. Nowadays, they are everywhere! Heck, even I made one! But still, capitals help to read it.

And as such, your `Mail` table should be all in lowercase.

---

You are extremelly inconsistent with your backticks. Either you use it or you don't use it! Don't mix both, please!

---

And now, to remove repetition.

- All messages are within an interval of 48 hours.
- All have `admin_status = 1`
- `admin_id` is always the same
- `sent_to` only changes if `subject like 'RE:%'`
- `mail_reply_status` is always `0`
- `user_id` is never `0`
- `core_event_inactive` shows twice with the value of `0`

With this information, I've made this:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE admin_status = 1
    AND admin_id = 4
    AND user_id = 0
    AND mail_reply_status = 0
    AND admin_inbox_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
    AND ( sent_to = 0 XOR ( sent_to = 4  AND subject LIKE 'RE:%' ) )
```

Since the `LIKE` is a really heavy check, we put it at the very last. Since SQL supports [short-circut evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), this positioning may result in faster queries. The slowest checks are the last ones.

It was really hard to follow if everything is 200% correct, but I hope I've nailed it. Please, comment if you see something innacurate.

Comment: Capitalization in SQL is a bit controversial, but everything else is good.

Comment: @200_success You are completely right about it. But since other keywords were already capitalized, and the `XOR` wasn't highlighted, I don't see anything bad in capitalizing everything.

Comment: Table name was actually lowercase, and this was written as one line on the file but tried to paste in a clear way here. All advices are noted though,thanks! Just the user_id part on your answer missed the 'not' 'user_id != 0' and added the core_event_id bit just like the sent_to XOR.

Comment: @Ekin Just give me around 20 minutes to edit the final code. I'm currently kinda busy. But thank you for noticing those point. They totally escaped me.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks a lot again, also can you give me a hint on how should I go with the core_event_inactive=0 bit when you have time?

Comment: @Ekin In what conditions does `core_event_inactive=0` is applied?

Comment: `subject like RE:%  and core_event_inactive=1 and admin_status = 1 and core_event_id =0` (sorry it's not 0 but 1 if that matters) --- this is for super admin, I'll need to add admin_id=4 if it's not super admin

Comment: @Ekin Sorry for the huge delay. Is that the whole condition for the `XOR`?